# Where do I store data that is to be read and parsed with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a web application and have been trying to save my data somewhere so that it can be parsed and utilized.

I've looked into saving the data locally and reading it. I've also looked into storing the data elsewhere to be read through some GET request. However, both seem to require odd workarounds to work which give me the impression that these solutions don't conform to what should regularly be done in this circumstance.

So then what am I to do when all I want is to load a file and parse it accordingly?

Comment: You only have two options: load locally or load remotely. Both of these are reasonable things to do depending on your goal. Maybe you should tell us more about what your actual goal is.

Comment: What kind of data are you talking about? User settings? Application data?

Comment: Loading it from some external URL would return "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource".

Comment: If you store it locally, users with multiple devices will see different data.

Comment: @OrangeReceptacle That shouldn't happen if your server is in the same domain as the application.

Comment: What I mean by data is just data that I've collected (points on a map) to be plotted that are written down in lat/long

Comment: Why do you need to store it anywhere? Does it need to be saved between uses of the application?

Comment: Data is usually saved in databases on the server.

Comment: If you're getting  "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'" then you need to consider where you're getting your data from. There are numerous answers on the site dealing with this issue.

Comment: I'm still very confused as to where the data is meant to be put if not locally and not in another domain. I've been looking all over and I get very vague answers.

Comment: You should be making AJAX calls to the same server where you get the application page.

Answer (score 0):

As many people mentionned, depending on your needs, you might be better served by storing your data on a server.

However, if you want to store your data locally, you can use the localStorage API.

When you store:

```
locastorage.setItem("MyData", JSON.stringify(dataToBeStored)
```

When you retrieve:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("MyData"))
```